# How to unit test ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing

I have a asp.net app that you upload a xml filenusing the fileupload control, and it is parsed into a list of objects and displayed in a grid view pretty simple stuff. but I have been asked to write some  unit tests. Im new to tdd and would like sum advice on how to write some unit tests.

This is what I have so far. Which I hard coded the xml file. Is there a way to unit test for the fileupload

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{

     string source = @"C:\Users\\Desktop\Web Application\ Web Application.Tests\LunchTest.xml";


    [TestMethod]
    public void ParseXmlTest()
    {
        XmlUlitilyClass x = new XmlUlitilyClass();

        Assert.AreEqual(x.ParseXml(source).Count, 4);
        Assert.AreEqual(x.ParseXml(source)[3].Name,"Roast of the day");
        Assert.AreEqual(x.ParseXml(source)[3].DesertIncluded, true);
        Assert.AreEqual(x.ParseXml(source)[0].Calories, 350);
        Assert.AreEqual(x.ParseXml(source)[1].Vegetarian, false);      
    }
}
```

Comment: extract `x.ParseXml(source)` to local variable, parse 5 times is too overhead :)

Comment: FYI, your question is about unit testing, not TDD. TDD is writing tests first - in your case, you have already written your application.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to unit test for the fileupload

Well, you definitely can't unit test the event handlers and other out bound stuff in `ASP.NET` like in your case the `FileUpload` control. Moreover you don't need to write unit test for fileupload control rather just check postivie/negative cases of the main logic. Yes, you can very well have the xml file name hard coded. Per your post what I see is, the main business logic here is:

1. unit testing the file handling logic. That is test what if a wrong file (or) non-existing file inputed. You can create separate unit test method for +ve/-ve cases where you can provide separate hardcoded file input.
2. XML parsing logic.

You can consider refactoring your code and put this two logic in separate method and unit test those method instead.

Per your comment, if you pro provide wrong file name then for sure runtime will throw an exception named `FileNotFoundException` you can catch it in your test method by using `ExpectedException` attribute. Example:

```
string source = @"C:\Users\\Desktop\Web Application\ Web Application.Tests\LunchTest.xml";

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FileNotFoundException),
    "Provided File doesn't exists.")]
public void TestFileNotExists()
{
   //your code goes here
}
```

Read more about unit testing in MSDN [A Unit Testing Walkthrough with Visual Studio Team Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625%28VS.80%29.aspx#vstsunittesting_topic5)

Comment: ok thank you. any advice how to unit test if a wrong file or  non-existing file inputed.new to unit testing sorry

Comment: Thank you having a look now

Comment: @TomGill, Welcome, consider accepting the answer  if it helped by clicking the check button. Pointing since you are a new user.

Comment: how do I test the filenot found not sure how to do it

Comment: @TomGill, just try to read from the file and that should do it.